# AWS Cognito Per User Roles (using AWS IOT)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I am currently prototyping an application that is backed by AWS IOT allowing users to control their devices.

My thoughts were to use AWS Cognito to authenticate users and limiting access to particular devices (topics) owned by that user via IAM roles.

I can see you can assign a role to a group of users, which would be great, but there is a very low cap on the number of groups allowed (25).

Am I missing a trick or is this a limitation of Cognito? If so, what would be the best way to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case for groups, an increase to the number of groups allowed can be given.